# Definition of monomial

Tags: polynomials, definition

I thought the definition of a monomial is an algebraic term that has no subtraction or addition. I saw on my online college homework that 2/x is not a monomial. Why?

Comment: Because your idea of the definition of a [monomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial) was wrong.

Comment: Oh so it's the same as 2x^-1, which has a negative exponent?

Comment: If you are working with [Laurent polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_polynomial) then $\,2x^{-1}\,$ is a monomial. But probably you are working only with ordinary polynomials, where the exponents of variables must be $\ge 0\ \ $

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As @Fundamental pointed out in a comment, your definition of monomial is wrong. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial) for a better definition.

Or here is a simpler definition. A monomial is a constant, a variable, or the product of constants and/or variables.

Details: The monomial is usually simplified to place the constant, if any, first, and to combine multiple copies of the same variable into a positive integral power of the variable. The variables are also usually written in alphabetical order.

Your expression $2/x$ does not meet my definition or Wikipedia's, so it is not a monomial.

Comment: Except  $\,2 x^{-1}\, $ is a monomial of a [Laurent polynomial.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_polynomial)

Comment: details relating to exponent in missing which is incorrect.